# Fórmulas en datatables

Tags: jquery, php7

es posible realizar cálculos tipo fórmulas de Excel a nivel de celdas en un datatable? Y si es posible me podrían indicar un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo? Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Deberías de subir lo que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ok dejame organizar el datatable y dejar las columnas en blanco donde quiero que las celdas reflejen un porcentaje con operaciones realizadas con celdas de otras columnas y anexo las imagenes y el codigo para que me expliques como podría realizar tales operaciones, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad deben cumplir con ciertos requisitos, los cuales se describen en [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)